# Writing model methods in Doctrine

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'd like to encapsulate functionality specific to certain models by including methods in the model class definitions. So, for example:

```
abstract class BaseUser extends DoctrineRecord {    

    public function setTableDefinition(){  
       //etc.  
    }  

    public function setUp(){  
       //etc.  
    } 

    public function getName(){  
       return $this->name  
    }
}
```

$this->name throws an error, as does $name. **Is it possible to access the model properties from here?**

Comment: I assume the missing `;` after `$this->name` is just a typo in the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties **can** be accessed using $this->propertyName as anyone would expect. My problem was that getProperty (getName in my example) is a function that the Doctrine framework automatically creates, creating a conflict when I tried to create my own. I changed the name to whatIsName() and everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

The `Basexxx` classes are abstract. You should add your method to the `User` class which extends `BaseUser`.

**[Edit]**
You can access properties of the base class in your child class using `$this->property`.  For example:

```
class User extends BaseUser {
   public function getWelcomeString() {
      return 'Welcome, ' . $this->name . '!';
   }
}
```

You can then access your custom functions in addition to all the base class properties from an instance of your chilod class:

```
$user = new User();
//Hydrate object from database
echo $user->getWelcomeString();     // implemented in your child class
echo 'Your name is ' . $user->name; // implemented in the base class
```

Comment: You're right - thank you. Do you know how I can access the model properties from these functions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Justin: I've updated my answer with an example.  Since you're new to SO I'll remind you to accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. Unfortunately, that's exactly what I've been trying, but an error is thrown that reads: "Undefined property: User::$name".

But I'm definitely defining the column correctly, because $user->name is returning as expected. It's just $user->getName() that's throwing the error.

Comment: Sorry, the "Undefined::Property" was an interpreter warning, not an error. Nonetheless, it wasn't working due to a naming conflict (see below).